# User kicked out from site after workflow finishes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I have a SharePoint server 2013 single server machine and Workflow Manager 1.0 installed on it. I'm testing a simple workflow, it just logs into history list. Every time I create an item, the workflow launches, and after I refresh the page, the user is no longer granted access to the site, it's like it has been kicked out of the site. When I open the site permissions, the user is no longer there.

What could be the possible reason for this weird behavior ?

Comment: that is really stange, did you check the LOGS if their is any thing which give the clue? also can you share the WF steps

Comment: Hi Waqas, here's a link for the log file : http://1drv.ms/1JkFQYR .
Let me know if you need more infos.